# postgresql escape to remove filepath not functioning in way expected

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
select distinct regexp_replace(name, E'^.*/|^.*\\', '') as name_,name from table
```

Seems to work on a sample filepath in [regexr](http://regexr.com), yet when I bring it to pgadmin I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence  (seg5 slice1 sdw1.gphd.local:1030 pid=179124)

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence  (seg5 slice1 sdw1.gphd.local:1030 pid=179124)
SQL state: 2201B
```

I cannot seem to crack the case.

Anyone experience this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that the escaped string needs the backslashes escaped and the regular expression needs the backslashes escaped.

```
\    - What you want
\\   - What you want, escaped for the Regex
\\\\ - What you want, escaped for the Regex, escaped for the escaped string
```

So, your query would be this:

```
select distinct regexp_replace(name, E'^.*/|^.*\\\\', '') as name_,name from table
```

(Docs on "[String Constants with C-style Escapes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)," section 4.1.2.2.)